# Visual studio add project reference with lib file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, c++-cli, project-reference

It looks like there has been some work done to add support for visual studio c++ project to project references.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MsBuild-to-resolve-and-copy-ProjectRefer/668834?space=62

If I setup a reference from GoogleTestSample to oqkern I am able to get a bunch of files copied locally.
oqkern.net.dll
oqkern.net.runtimeconfig.json
and also a bunch of other dlls

[image]

**Is there a way I can get the oqkern.net.lib file to be copied locally as well?**

I seem to need that to be able to compile without getting linker errors.

I think the property below takes care of being able to include source files from the referenced project:

[image]

**I have tried to use the "content file" approach but it didn't seem to work.**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Library Include="..\..\src\oqkern\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\oqkern.net.lib">
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">true</DeploymentContent>
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">true</DeploymentContent>
    </Library>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I'm not sure if the content file approach happens soon enough, I need the file copied before the build so things compile.

**A pre-build event works:**

```
xcopy /y /d  "$(SolutionDir)src\oqkern\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\oqkern.net.lib" "$(OutDir)"
```

Comment: You're halfway there.  Right-click the project > Add > Existing Item and select the oqkern.net.lib file you want to copy.  That makes it part of the project, select it and set its Content property to True.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work.  The file is required for the compile of GoogleTestSample to succeed.  Do content files get copied after compile succeeds?
I was able to get it working with a prebuld event.